# typescrips XXX.isSupported is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

implementing JS library on
Typescript

If I use this function in JS it works fine

```
_clickHandler() {
TouchID.isSupported()
  .then(authenticate)
  .catch(error => {
    AlertIOS.alert('TouchID not supported');
  });
```

}

But when using it in Typescript

> import * as TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';

```
function FingerPrintCheck() {
  console.log('altered');
  TouchID.isSupported()
  .then(authenticate)
  .catch((error : any) => {
    AlertIOS.alert('TouchID not supported');
  });
}
```

I get the error:

> TouchID.isSupported is not a function

So why is TS not recognizing the function? do I need to instantiate parameter or do something similar

Edit:
if I import as

> import TouchID from "react-native-touch-id";

I will get:

> [ts] Module ''react-native-touch-id'' has no default export

Comment: Have you also tried to add @types/react-native-touch-id to your dependencies?

Comment: hi @samsonthehero, yes no errors on import header

Comment: In the tests file for this module (the typings) they are importing isSupported differently, see: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native-touch-id/react-native-touch-id-tests.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `TouchID` as

```
import TouchID from "react-native-touch-id";
```

Comment: hi, if I import as your suggestion I will get: [ts] Module ''react-native-touch-id'' has no default export

Comment: I can see few users posted same issue on `gitHub` regarding the same. Could you try with `var TouchID = require('react-native-touch-id');`  as suggested on https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id

Comment: hi Spider, yes I've tried, but I get the same error.